# Cyclomatic complexity for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there any tool for showing the cyclomatic complexity for Visual Studio in the left hand bar where the debug symbol goes?

I seem to remember there was an addin for Resharper but don't think it works in 4.5

Has anyone seen any similar tools, other than the built in support in VS

Answer (score 2):

A standalone tool with lots of metrics (including cc) is [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe CodeRush had it 'interactively'.. but heck, why bother, there are sources on the web that will give you commercial-free ideas and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Coderush from Developer Express will do this and it works well.  I vouch for it. (and have no relation to the company other than a long time customer)

Answer (score 1):

McCabe IQ ([www.mccabe.com/iq.htm](http://www.mccabe.com/iq.htm)) developed by the man who authored Cyclomatic Complexity, Tom McCabe.

Answer (score 1):

[Code Metrics](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=CodeMetrics) is an excellent free plug-in for reflector that analyzes code size & complexity.

Comment: Forgot about that ... I've used it before as well.  It's good.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 Team System (or just VS 2008 Developer Edition) has Code Metrics. 
[StudioTools](http://www.exactmagic.com/products/studiotools/) is a free addin for VS 2005 and VS 2008.  NDepend is good too.